# Cordova plugin camera shows "Take Photo" even if PHOTOLIBRARY was chosen as a source type

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins, ionic-view

I am using Cordova-plugin-camera to upload User photo from phone library. For that, I pass `sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY`. These are my settings:

```
cameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  targetWidth: 600,
  targetHeight: 600,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
  correctOrientation: true
};
```

When I run the application in Ionic View I still see the option "Take Photo". I click it, my camera opens and lets me make a photo. After I make a photo, phone redirects me to the photo library. So, basically, yes I can't take a photo, but the option is still there. Is it possible not to show it somehow? It confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY by the number 0